# Auto populate field base on what was entered in another field simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input

I was trying to figure out how to auto-populate the input value base on what was entered in another input field using javascript. Here's my code:

```
<script>
add = document.getElementById('address').value;
city = document.getElementById('city').value;
state = document.getElementById('state').value;
zip = document.getElementById('zip').value;
compAdd = add+" "+city+" "+state+" "+zip;
function showAdd(){
    document.getElementById('shipadd1').value=compAdd;
    document.getElementById('add1').innerHTML=compAdd;
}
</script>

<form action="" onchange="showAdd();">

Home Address: <input id="address" name="address" type="text"  /><br/>
Apt or Suite Number: <input id="suite" name="suite" type="text" /><br/>
City/Town: <input id="city" name="city" type="text" /><br/>
State:<select id="state" name="state" value="">...</select><br/>
Zip:<input id="zip" name="zip" type="text" value=""/><br/>


<p> Select Shipping Address Below: </p>

<input type="checkbox" id="shipping-address-1" name="address1" value=""><span id="shiadd1">(Print auto-populated shipping address here...)</span>

<input type="checkbox" id="shipping-address-2" name="address2" value="">ABC Corp 123 Main Street, My City, State Zip
</form>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged jQuery? I see none.

Comment: Are you trying to do this without jQuery?

Comment: If it can be done with JQuery then, yes. Either way should work for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made a [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/justinmichaels/Wnyhg/1/) based on what you're asking for.

**HTML**

```
Home Address:
<input id="address" name="address" type="text" />
<br/>Apt or Suite Number:
<input id="suite" name="suite" type="text" />
<br/>City/Town:
<input id="city" name="city" type="text" />
<br/>State:
<select id="state" name="state" value="">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
</select>
<br/>Zip:
<input id="zip" name="zip" type="text" value="" />
<br/>
<p>Select Shipping Address Below:</p>
<input type="checkbox" id="shipping-address-1" name="address1" value="">
<label for="shipping-address-1" id="shiadd1">(Print auto-populated shipping address here...)</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="shipping-address-2" name="address2" value="">
<label for="shipping-address-2">ABC Corp 123 Main Street, My City, State Zip</label>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("#address,#suite,#city,#state,#zip").change(function () {
    var addressArray = [$("#address").val(), $("#suite").val(), $("#city").val(), $("#state").val(), $("#zip").val()];
    $("#shiadd1").text(addressArray.join(' '));
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I made a general example :

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="first">
<input type="text" class="second">
```

**javascript**

```
$(".first").on('keyup',function(){
    $(".second").val($(this).val());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fmdwv/1/

For your purpose :

```
$("#address").on('change', function(){
  $("#shipping-address-1").val($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Hey , this works excellent with simple inputs!But why its not working with type="date" ?:(

Comment: It's not taking the last letter. I mean If I enter an address, USA then it's displaying on US

Comment: @user9437856 updating: you should use `keyup` and not `keydown`

Comment: @steo, Thanks for the reply, actually I found my solution using this code. I have to display the firstname and lastname in the fullname fields function updateFullName() {
    $("#fullname").val($("#firstname").val()+ ' ' + $("#lastname").val());
}

$("#firstname, #lastname").on('input', updateFullName);

Answer (score 0):

The `onchange` event should be used in the `<input>` tags themselves and not in the `<form>`.

Answer (score 0):

Create simple html file with two input text box. The first input text box will take the input from the user about a date format and second input text box will display the current date on this format.
After the completion of first step, implement date selection library to select a date and format it according to the user input given in first input text b