# Auto-Populate a field in a form depending on a formula and previous field input

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am needing some help with Auto-Populating 2 fields on a form based on the input of the previous fields in that form from the user, all based on a formula. My entire web application works, just this functionality is confusing me and I do not know how to go about solving it. Please forgive me if this is a fairly easy/obvious approach.

[Formula and Pricing Module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtzEy.png)

[Other Instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wTO5.png)

[models.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJvL2.png)

[routes.py: only showing that specific forms route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvDer.png)

[forms.py: showing only the Quote form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wcIs.png)

**requestAQuote.html**

```html
{% extends "template.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST" action="">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Request a Quote today!</legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.gallons_requested.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {% if form.gallons_requested.errors %}
                        {{ form.gallons_requested(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.gallons_requested.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.gallons_requested(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.delivery_date.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {% if form.delivery_date.errors %}
                        {{ form.delivery_date(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.delivery_date.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.delivery_date(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.request_date.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {% if form.request_date.errors %}
                        {{ form.request_date(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.request_date.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.request_date(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.delivery_location.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {% if form.delivery_location.errors %}
                        {{ form.delivery_location(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.delivery_location.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.delivery_location(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.delivery_contact_name.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {% if form.delivery_contact_name.errors %}
                        {{ form.delivery_contact_name(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.delivery_contact_name.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.delivery_contact_name(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.delivery_contact_phone.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {% if form.delivery_contact_phone.errors %}
                        {{ form.delivery_contact_phone(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.delivery_contact_phone.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.delivery_contact_phone(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.delivery_contact_email.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {% if form.delivery_contact_email.errors %}
                        {{ form.delivery_contact_email(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.delivery_contact_email.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.delivery_contact_email(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.suggested_price.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {% if form.suggested_price.errors %}
                        {{ form.suggested_price(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.suggested_price.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.suggested_price(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.total_amount_due.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {% if form.total_amount_due.errors %}
                        {{ form.total_amount_due(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.total_amount_due.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.total_amount_due(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.get_price(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add some javascript code to auto-populate it based on your other field.
please refer to this
[Auto populate field base on what was entered in another field simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474499/auto-populate-field-base-on-what-was-entered-in-another-field-simultaneously)